# Meaning of "long past the point"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> We are ***long past the point*** where the story of Donald Trump became stranger and more lurid than a Hollywood movie.

What does "long past the point" mean?

(This quote came from a translated Chinese news article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, it simply means that the *time* when Donald Trump's story became stranger and more lurid than a Hollywood movie *is long gone*.

In other words, it happened *way back in time*.

It is worth mentioning here that the time is not quantified in the sentence. Rather, it just stresses on the point that it was a long time ago. Exactly how long ago is unknown.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! BTW past here is a Verb?

Comment: @SteveChoi: No, _past_ is a preposition. _Long_ is an adverb modifying the whole PP _past the point_ - it can only be used in this way when it refers to a length of time, so it constrains "past the point" to mean in a temporal sense: "a long time after the point when ..."